# php does not work with apostrophe in mysql query on linux server

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I'm shucked with a strange problem. when i execute this query from my phpmyadmin it works fine and returns 2 results . But When we are executing this Query form php page it returns 0 result.

```
$query = "SELECT distinct(vtiger_products.product_no) FROM `vtiger_products` 
    INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity VC ON VC.crmid = vtiger_products.productid 
    inner join vtiger_tree_product vtp on vtiger_products.productid = vtp.productid"; 


$custom_conditions = '  cf.cf_1399 = "'.$_REQUEST['size'].'"';
$temp ='Where vtiger_products.hisotrization_status='Current' 
        AND vtiger_products.productid > 0 
        AND VC.deleted = 0 
        AND vtp.nodeid in (425,426,427,428,430,431,457,458,459,460,480,488,502,510,514,515,516,517,518,519,520,521,525,526,527,528,529)';

if ($custom_conditions) {
    $query .= " inner JOIN vtiger_productcf cf on cf.productid = vtiger_products.productid ";
    $conditions .= " AND ( " . str_replace('""','\""',str_replace("''","\''",$custom_conditions)) . " ) ";
}

$query = $query.$temp . $conditions; 






SELECT distinct(vtiger_products.product_no) FROM `vtiger_products` 
INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity VC ON VC.crmid = vtiger_products.productid 
inner join vtiger_tree_product vtp on vtiger_products.productid = vtp.productid 
inner JOIN vtiger_productcf cf on cf.productid = vtiger_products.productid 
Where vtiger_products.hisotrization_status='Current' 
    AND vtiger_products.productid > 0 
    AND VC.deleted = 0 
    AND vtp.nodeid in (425,426,427,428,430,431,457,458,459,460,480,488,502,510,514,515,516,517,518,519,520,521,525,526,527,528,529) 
    AND ( cf.cf_1399 = "20'" );
```

Waiting for your response Thanks

Comment: Are you using a variable in php to set one of the values in the query? If so, please post the PHP code aswell.

Comment: Please post the whole line from the PHP file, not just the SQL string

Comment: show us your php script

Comment: just looking at your post, the fact that vtiger_products is monospaced means you used backticks, and not apostrophes

Comment: If the query is inside a PHP string literal, you'll need to escape any uses of the same quote that you used to delimit the string.

Comment: Hi Seunhaab,
i have updated code can you please look it to this

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the the php variables into the query by using function mysql_real_escape_string(Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement).

```
e.g.mysql_real_escape_string($user);
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. Please mysqli_* equivilents or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple:

Wrong:

```
$query = '... set test = 'blah' where ...'; (' before blah terminates the string)
```

Solution 1:

```
$query = '... set test = \'blah\' where ...'; (escaping)
```

Solution 2:

```
$query = "... set test = 'blah' where ..."; (double quotes aren't terminated by single quotes)
```

Please note that "Hello, $test !" evaluates $test while 'Hello, $test !' does not.